# Multiple Jetty Domains on single SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, ports

I have a machine running Jetty. On there I have multiple jetty instances running on different ports. For instance I have the "live" version running on the default port 80. I also have the "R&D" version running on the same machine but on port 2280. This works just fine, however the client needed to add SSL so the default would now be running off port 443. The issue is when I try to run both at the same time the R&D version will fail because it is trying to map to 443 because of the SSL. The config still has the R&D pointing to 2280 but does not start. Is there a way to run both at the same time using the single SSL certificate? I tried adding connectors in the jetty.xml file but that did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the connector?  You can definitely configure the port of the connector.

I typically run Jetty programmatically, and my code is as follows:

```
int httpsPort = ...;
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setSecureScheme("https");
httpConfig.setSecurePort(httpsPort);

SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
//  configure sslContextFactory: keystore, session timeout, exlcluded protocols etc...

ServerConnector httpsCon = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"), new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
httpsCon.setPort(httpsPort);
server.addConnector(httpsCon);
```

Sorry, I am not sure how to configure that via XML server configuration, but they tend to map very closely between XML config and programmatic config.

Comment: My jetty.xml has: 
<Call name="addConnector">
   <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
         <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
         <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="2280"/></Set>
         <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
         <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
         <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
         <Set name="confidentialPort">2443</Set>
 <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
 <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
  </New>
 </Arg>
</Call>

Comment: `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` is for an old now EOL (End of Life) version of Jetty.  That class no longer exists on current/stable/supported versions of Jetty.

Comment: Is there a different way to configure this by not using the SelectChannelConnector? I understand that that version 8.1.9 is now EOL but I wouldn't think this would be a new feature. Unless it was a bug that was fixed in a later version.